# What chemistry are lithium-ion AA rechargeable batteries using?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, battery-chemistry

Recently I've seen rechargeable lithium-ion AA's for sale, but I sure don't want ICR in my pocket or anywhere else near me, and they are 1.5VDC as needed for standard AA, which means something interesting is going on.  Anyone know chemistries for any of these, or the best ways to find out?

Please note that I'm asking what sort of lithium-ion: IMR, ICR, INR...?

Comment: Lithium-Ion, let me guess Lithium-ion chemistry maybe?

Comment: Your other question has an answer which answers this.

Comment: Questions about **undocumented consumer products** are not on topic here.  Even if that were not the case, your question would not be answerable, because there are multiple possible ways of creating such a product, and an answer could only apply to a particular one.  Without specificity how is anyone to know which manufacturer's choices would apply?   If you don't have a **data sheet**, it is **off topic**.

Answer (score 0):

Lithium-ion.

The internal battery is not connected to the external battery terminals. The battery operates at its own voltage (i.e. lithium-ion) and uses a DC-DC converter to deliver 1.5V to the external battery terminals.

That's the interesting thing going on.   Well, not quite.

We *hope* that internal electronics also provides battery charge/discharge protection for the lithium cell. But don't count on it.  The 3 vendors you have linked so far are all "cheap Cheese" and deliberately evade the laboratory testing required for a product to enter the US market, e.g. into the bricks-and-mortar retail channel, or **true** domestic mail-order e.g. from sears.com, Grainger, etc.  They are using either direct mail from Asia, or drop-shipping through Amazon's warehouse, where Amazon claims to be "only a platform", leaving *no one at all* responsible for product safety, and somehow, this is "OK".

*That's* the interesting thing going on!